# Importing Vuetify Styles Individually

Tags: sass, vuetify.js

I'm using Vuetify in one of my projects. The problem is that the recommended way of importing the styles is by including a pre-rendered vuetify.min.css. The file, for me, is still too big at 452Kb.

Since I'm not using all of vuetify's components as of now (I'm not using 99% of the styles), I'd like to import only those core styles and a couple of styles related to components that I use. I'd like my final stylesheet to be as lean as possible.

I see that it's using sass files as its source. Is there a way to compile my own custom vuetify css using those sass files? If so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The style loading should be automatically handled if you are using the latest VUE CLI tool-set with [vuetify-loader](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify-loader) and followed the installation instructions correctly there should be no need to specify a line to import styles.

Ensure in `vue.config.js` this is set:

```js
  transpileDependencies: [
    'vuetify'
  ],
```

Also in certain circumstances you may need to manually register some components when you see errors related to trying to load missing components, here is an example how to resolve edge case missing Vuetify componenets:

```js
// src/plugins/vuetify.js

import Vuetify, { VBtn, VDivider, VIcon, VLayout, VSnackbar } from 'vuetify/lib'

Vue.use(Vuetify, {
  components: { VBtn, VDivider, VIcon, VLayout, VSnackbar }
})

export default new Vuetify({})
```

```js
// src/main.js

import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify'

...

new Vue({
  router,
  vuetify,
  render: h => h(App)

}).$mount('#app')
```

I do however import Vuetify variables for use in custom SCSS code:

```
@import "~vuetify/src/styles/settings/variables";
```